# Why does deleting a non-existent CloudKit record apparently succeed?

Tags: ios, macos, cloudkit

The following sample code illustrates attempting to delete a CloudKit record that doesn't exist in the database (the recordId is initialised but no such record is ever saved in the database). I would have expected an error return but in fact it returns as if the deletion was successful. Obviously I know what the problem is and have fixed it in the real code but am I wrong to expect some sort of error return from CloudKit?

If you agree its misleading I will happily file a bug report so it can be fixed.

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            deleteIt(recordID: CKRecord.ID(recordName: "Fake record"))   //Made up recordID for non-existant record
        }, label: {
            Text("Delete Non-existant record")
        })
    }
}

func deleteIt(recordID: CKRecord.ID) {
    let iCloudDatabase = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.revcomputing.BWACHotel").privateCloudDatabase
    print ("Attempting to delete non-existant 'record': \(recordID)")
    
    iCloudDatabase.delete(withRecordID: recordID) { (deletedRecordID, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            if deletedRecordID == nil {
                print ("❌ Record: \(recordID) wasn't deleted")
            }
            if error == nil {
                print ("❌ iCloud returned no error after deleting 'record': \(deletedRecordID!)")
            } else {
                print ("❌ CloudKit returned error: \(error!) trying to delete'record': \(deletedRecordID!)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Console listing (MacOS):

2021-01-09 08:06:12.948619+1000 CloudKitDeleteError[2709:120918] Metal API Validation Enabled

Attempting to delete non-existant 'record': <CKRecordID: 0x600003dcfbc0; recordName=Fake record, zoneID=_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**>
❌ iCloud returned no error after deleting 'record': <CKRecordID: 0x600003df90e0; recordName=Fake record, zoneID=_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**>

Thanks...

Robert

Comment: I guess there are two ways of looking at this. 1. Attempting to delete a non-existent record is an error. Or 2, The post-condition of a delete operation is that the record no longer exists and deleting a non- existent record definitely satisfies that. Given that CloudKit works across multiple devices where the database is only loosely consistent ignoring, the "error" and focussing on the post condition seems like a sensible approach.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I appreciate your input. Of course I lean towards case 1, as my natural assumption in seeing the record I was trying to delete still visible in the dashboard was to look at the result returned from the delete operation. Seeing no error flagged, I spent time both googling and examining my code for what could have caused this to occur. A simple error return would have made the cause of the problem obvious immediately in my opinion.